# Is there a name for right a prism with convex bases?

Tags: geometry, dice

Is there a name for a prism where the bases are convex, as in, they curve or jut outward?

**Context and application:** These shapes can be used to create fair dice of "wacky" sides like a d3 (die with 3 sides), d5, d7, d9, and so on. A d6 is attached below as an example; there is a shape similar to a prism, but the bases have a shape that makes it jut outward, so that it will never land on those bases.

[image: d6]

Answer (score 1):

If the pointed ends are achieved by simply adding a single vertex at each pole, these ["long" or "barrel" dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_dice) are called [elongated bipyramids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elongated_bipyramid) (typically right but with irregular faces). For even-sided dice, there's also the option of [gyroelongated bipyramids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroelongated_bipyramid), in which case the numbered faces are triangles.